# Parallelize Map and ParallelMap

Tags: bugs, parallelization, map

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 11.2**

---

It is stated in the documentation that

> `Parallelize[Map[f, expr]]` is equivalent to `ParallelMap[f, expr]`.

But what about these examples?

```
ParallelMap[#^2 &, f[x] + g[y]]
(* f[x]^2 + g[y]^2 *)

Parallelize[Map[#^2 &, f[x] + g[y]]]
(* f[x^2] + g[y^2] *)
```

Comment: I would report this to Wolfram Support. The workaround is to always use a list as the second argument of `Map` when parallelizing.

Comment: Can reproduce -- I would report this as well.

Comment: I would like to know in which versions of Mathematica this bug has been observed. Currently, I use M 7.0.1, and in it the two inputs produce identical outputs, the same as in the first one above.

Comment: @innaiz I'm running mma 10.4

Comment: With versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 on Windows 7 x64 I get outputs as shown in the question. Considering the above comment by @innaiz, the bug was introduced in version 8.0.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I did a bit of debugging to find the cause of the problem.  After I found it, the problem no longer seems as outrageous as it looked at first sight.

The root cause of the problem is the following property of `Plus`:

```
Plus[x]
(* x *)
```

This means that unlike `List`, `Plus` cannot be used as a container that can be split into smaller parts and then put together again.

This works:

```
Join[Plus[a, b], Plus[c, d]]
(* a + b + c + d *)
```

This does not:

```
Join[Plus[a], Plus[c, d]]
(* Join[a, c + d] *)
```

Partitioning is the first step to parallelization—each partition (or batch) will be sent to a different subkernel.  You have precisely two elements to evaluate (`f[x]` and `g[x]`), so they get partitioned into two batches of length 1 each.  `Plus[f[x], g[x]]` ends up split into `Plus[f[x]]` and `Plus[g[x]]`. At one point these are (incorrectly) allowed to evaluate to `f[x]` and `g[x]`.

#### More detailed analysis

The literal expression the system ends up constructing (and submitting for parallel evaluation) is:

```
HoldComplete[
 (sq /@ # &)[Unevaluated[Plus[f[x]]]], 
 (sq /@ # &)[Unevaluated[Plus[g[x]]]]
]
```

`sq` here is `#^2&`—I am going to use `sq` from now on to make it easier to follow what is happening.  The two elements within `HoldComplete` are the two size-1 batches, with processing ready to be applied to them.

Now watch carefully what happens if we evaluate one of these elements:

- First, the `Unevaluated` gets stripped.
- Then we get `sq /@ Plus[f[x]]`
- Now the `Plus` evaluates because it has a single argument. If it had at least two, it wouldn't. We get `sq /@ f[x]`
- And then we get `f[sq[x]]` and finally `f[x^2]`.

An interesting note is that if we had `Map[sq]` instead of `sq /@ # &`, then no further evaluation would take place after the `Unevaluated` gets stripped, and the problem would be averted (*hint: perhaps this could be a good fix*).

So if you thought that `Map[f]` and `f /@ #&` were the same thing, here's one example that proves them different.

#### Why is there a difference between `ParallelMap[...]` and `Parallelize[Map[...]]`?

`ParallelMap[f, arg]` effectively translates to

```
ParallelCombine[
  Function[e, Map[f,Unevaluated[e]]],
  arg
]
```

<sup>see `Combine.m`, line 324</sup>

`Parallelize[Map[f, arg]]` effectively translates to

```
 ParallelCombine[
   Map[f, #]&,
   arg
 ]
```

The latter lacks an `Unevaluated`, which is the root of the problem.

<sup>see `Evaluate.m`, line 137</sup>

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That's actually a relief. What happened was that I typed `HoldAllComplete` instead of `HoldComlete` when I tried it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Nat Read the explanation and make your own judgement. Consider the rest of the post an opinion.

Comment: @Nat OK, I removed that section since I agree that it would be good to have this fixed.  When I first saw the problem, it seemed outrageous and a terrible bug. But after I looked at why it happens, it's hard for me to blame the developer because I would probably have fallen into the same trap. I don't want to argue about what to call it, but yes: it is confusing, a bad user experience, and the fact that `ParallelMap` does not do this proves that it can be fixed.  However, after looking at the implementation, I strongly suspect that it wouldn't be hard to construct an example ...

Comment: @Nat that also breaks `ParallelMap`.  And I am a bit annoyed with Mathematica because it seems to difficult to robustly handle such cases :)

Comment: Hah yeah, I'm a bit annoyed with Mathematica for its general lack of extensibility.  I'm guessing that Wolfram got so caught up in CA because the whole Turing completeness of Rule 110 seemed like a good primitive ontology for a future system, but then he hit the same incompleteness barrier that screwed Hilbert's program, reducing Mathematica from what he'd dreamed to a [CISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing)-like API engine for relatively short scripts.  Then, whenever stuff gets stacked too far, it does... well, like the bug in this question.

Comment: @Nat I looked at why the two differ, and now it looks more like a bug again.  I updated the answer.  Will log off for today, goo night!

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for your post. I notice that your implementation of `ParallelMap` is not as in the system. The `ParallelCombine` has attribute `HoldAllComplete`, while `ParallelMap` has `HoldRest`. For example `ParallelCombine[Function[e, Map[sq, Unevaluated[e]]], 
 Unevaluated@Plus[f[x]]]` gives `f[x]^2`, but `ParallelMap[sq, Unevaluated@Plus[f[x]]]` gives `f[x^2]` (of course if you add the attribute `HoldAllComplete` to `ParallelMap` then they give the same thing).

Comment: @Mher I do not understand your comments.  I don't have "my implementation of ParallelMap". I am simply showing—in an admittedly oversimplified, but still relevant way—how `ParallelMap` and `Parallelize[Map[...]]` are *actually* implemented.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK then, maybe I treated it too formal. But anyway, if the issue is evaluation of the expression, why `ParallelMap[sq, Unevaluated[Plus[f[x]]]]` gives `f[x^2]` instead of `f[x]^2` ?

Comment: @Mher It seems to me that that is an entirely separate question from what we have been discussing so far.  You would need to look at the implementation of `ParallelMap` to see the exact reason, but this behaviour is not surprising. Every evaluation step provides one more chance for the `Unevaluated` to get stripped, and once it does, `Plus[f[x]]` changes into `f[x]`.  Plain `Map` has no additional internal evaluation steps.  `ParallelMap` is implemented in Mathematica, so it has many.