# Why is Unevaluated[#]& different from Unevaluated?

Tags: functional-style, hold

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};
Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}
(* {Unevaluated[a], Unevaluated[b], Unevaluated[c]} *)
Unevaluated[#]& /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}
(* {Unevaluated[1], Unevaluated[2], Unevaluated[3]} *)
```

Why are the outputs different? What is the difference between using `Unevaluated`  and `Unevaluated[#]&`? I thought that for any function `f` we could use "`f`" interchangeably with "`f[#]&`". Is there a special interaction between Unevaluated and Map?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130890/5467)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The two are not equivalent. *Even if* `f` lacks special attributes.

Assuming no special attributes are present, a function's arguments are always evaluated before the function is called. This event occurs twice with `f[#] &[x]`, but only once with `f[x]`. Now, if everything has been fully evaluated, then you won't see a difference, but if something is marked as "do not evaluate", then you can see a difference.

(This can be very counter-intuitive if you're only used to traditional programming languages.)

Here's a counterexample:

```
Print     [Unevaluated[2 + 2]]      (* prints 2 + 2 *)
Print[#] &[Unevaluated[2 + 2]]      (* prints 4     *)
```

However, I *think* (though I'm not 100% sure I've considered all the cases) that the following two *would* be equivalent if `f` lacks special attributes:

```
f
f[Unevaluated[#]] &
```

Comment: OK, so you've showed there exists an extra step. But what exactly is this step?

Comment: @Ruslan: I'm not sure how to point to it and say "there it is", but if you understand that Unevaluated only suppresses 1 step of evaluation whereas Hold suppresses all steps, then you can see that invoking  an extra function with an expression will add an extra evaluation step for the expression. It's simply a consequence of a function's arguments getting evaluated before the function is called. That happens twice in the second example but once in the first (because there are two function calls in the second but one in the first).

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the difference between `Unevaluated` and `Hold`.

Comment: @Ruslan: Yeah, you're probably not the only one. I had to get my hands dirty and write a whole simulator in Mathematica before really understanding this stuff in the language. It's definitely not easy to get what's really going on if you only use it casually.

Comment: I wouldn't call not listing every different *wrong*, but you make a good point.  Here's how the very same thing lead to a problem in the parallelization framework: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138490/12

Comment: There are other differences too, e.g. `Function` silently discarding extra arguments.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I didn't mean "not listing every difference" is what made it wrong, I meant literally the first sentence (*"That is only true if the function has no special attributes."*) is simply false. (And yes, pedantically it's true in the mathematical sense of "only if", but false for the normal English sense.) The part about discarding extra arguments is indeed true but doesn't really seem relevant given the question was about a single argument, unless I'm missing something/misunderstanding it. (?)

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad for the clarification. It seems that there is a lot of subtlety hidden in the simple statement from the `Unevaluated` documentation: "Unevaluated works only where it appears; it is not propagated." Sometimes it is propagated a little bit; other times it's not propagated at all; and to tell the difference takes a bit of experimentation.

Comment: @Ruslan, the extra step becomes clear when you compare `Trace[Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}]` with `Trace[Unevaluated[#] & /@ Unevaluated@{a, b, c}]`: in the second one, there's a point where you have `(Unevaluated[#1] &)[a]` which is converted to `(Unevaluated[#1] &)[1]` before becoming `Unevaluated[1]`. So the extra step is "supplying the anonymous function with its argument".

Comment: @Roman: oops, just noticed I never replied to your subsequent comment. As I understand it, `Unevaluated` is just a wrapper that disappears after being `Evaluate`d, kind of like how you could say a lambda (`&`) is  a wrapper that goes away after you call it with `[]`, except that evaluation happens automatically. So that means it will propagate and 'not' go away if it appears inside an `Unevaluated` (or `Hold`'ed, etc.) context of its own.

Answer (score 25):

> I thought that for any function `f` we could use "`f`" interchangeably with "`f[#]&`".

That is only true if the function has no special attributes.  [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) effectively removes those attributes, and all other special behaviour.

For example,

```
Hold[1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)

Hold[#] &[1 + 1]
(* Hold[2] *)

Function[x, Hold[x], HoldAll][1 + 1]
(* Hold[1 + 1] *)
```

(For the last one, see the 3rd argument of [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html).)

Please read [Evaluation of Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressionsOverview.html) at least up to [Nonstandard Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html).  As I remember it should contain the answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs, even though this is not the right answer in the context of `Unevaluated`, it is still useful to know in other contexts.

Answer (score 16):

The head `Unevaluated` is a symbol with the `HoldAllComplete` attribute. The head `Unevaluated[#]&` is not a symbol and thus has no attributes to suppress *Mathematica*'s evaluation of its tail.