# Construct really identical function (the same as Length)

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation, built-in-symbols, attributes

```
In[1] Length[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]
Out[1] 4
```

**Q1)** Can we construct a function named `f`, such that `f` and `Length` behaves just in the same way?

I've checked that `Attributes[Length]` yields `{Protected}`, which is not very important here.

So I defined `f` as `f[x_]:=Length[x]` or `f[x__]:=Length[x]` and thought that was all.

But contrary to my expectation,

```
In[2] f[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]
Out[2] 0
```

**Q2)** In general, how can we assure that the two function `f`,`g` (one of them may be built-in) behaves just in the same way? (Except some very very freaky, forced cases.)
From the above example, it is not enough to consider only their definitions and attributes.
There are somethiing more.

Comment: Related: [Why is `Unevaluated[#]&` different from `Unevaluated`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163291/why-is-unevaluated-different-from-unevaluated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's instructive to look at the output of `TracePrint`.

```
Length[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]] // TracePrint
```

```
(* Out: *)

 Length[Unevaluated[1+1+1+1]]
  Length
 Length[1+1+1+1]
 4
```

Whereas

```
f[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]] // TracePrint
```

```
(* Out: *)

 f[Unevaluated[1+1+1+1]]
  f
 f[1+1+1+1]
 Length[1+1+1+1]
  Length
  1+1+1+1
   Plus
   1
   1
   1
   1
  4
 Length[4]
 0
```

Let's try something similar, but different, before explaining this:

```
g = Length;
g[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]] // TracePrint
```

```
(* Out: *)

 g[Unevaluated[1+1+1+1]]
  g
  Length
 Length[1+1+1+1]
 4
```

What's going on here?

It has to do with the order in which Mathematica evaluates expressions. There's a fair bit I'm leaving out here, but here are the important details for this case. Consider an arbitrary expression `h[x1, x2, ...]`, and let's walk through the evaluation process.

1. The head of the expression `h` is evaluated as an expression in its own right (just as we would any other expression; that is, it is run through this process). Let's refer to whatever expression `h` evaluates to (which most times, is simply `h` itself) as `h1`. (Note: arguments are not considered here. This is akin to putting `h` in a cell by itself and hitting Shift+Enter.)
2. Each of the arguments `x1`, `x2`, ... is evaluated. If any of them begin with `Unevaluated`, we strip off the `Unevaluated` head, and then skip evaluation of that expression.
3. Apply any downvalues for `h1`, i.e., rules that are used to transform the cases where `h1` is given arguments. So, e.g., rules that are created by definitions like `h1[x_] := ...`. Then, **evaluate the resulting expression.**

This process is recursive, so when we evaluate the resulting expression, we start over again at the top.

With this in mind, let's make sense of the previous evaluations.

1. `Length[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]`. `Length` evaluates to itself; `Unevaluated` is stripped off; and we apply the definition (downvalue) of `Length` to `Plus[1,1,1,1]` directly, which is `4`. (Note that this downvalue for `Length` is built-in, so you won't find it under `DownValues[Length]`.)
2. `f[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]`. `f` evaluates to itself (as a bare expression—we're not applying to arguments yet!); `Unevaluated` is stripped off; and we apply the downvalues of `f` to `Plus[1,1,1,1]`. Here, that downvalue is given by `f[x_] := Length[x]`, so we substitute `Plus[1,1,1,1]` into `Length` to get `Length[Plus[1,1,1,1]]`. Now, here's the crucial bit—since this came from a downvalue, we now **evaluate that expression**! In the previous example (`Length[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]`), at this stage, we applied the (built-in) downvalue of `Length` to `Plus[1,1,1,1]` immediately to get `4`. But here, we're starting the evaluation process for this expression from the beginning again (step 1); so, we evaluate `Length`, then evaluate `Plus[1,1,1,1]` to get `4`, then evaluate `Length[4]`, which is `0`.
3. `g = Length; g[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]`. Here, we evaluate the head (`g`) first. Since `g`, by itself (no arguments), evaluates to the symbol `Length`, we then proceed with the evaluation process with `Length` in front: strip off `Unevaluated` and skip evaluation of `Plus[1,1,1,1]`, then see if there are any downvalues we can apply to the head of the expression. But, oh wait...the head has already been evaluated to `Length`! And there is indeed a built-in downvalue for the head `Length`, which gets us `4` (just as it did in (1) at this same stage).

So, the moral (and solution)?

**Define the head to be `Length` directly!**

Since the head is *always* evaluated first, no matter what (unless your expression is, say, being examined by some *other* expression, which is preventing evaluation from happening normally), you can be safe defining `g = Length`. This even applies for the more complicated things—upvalues, `Hold*` attributes (even `HoldAllComplete`!), and the rest. All that is *only* taken into consideration after the head of the expression, as an expression in its own right, is fully evaluated.

The only thing that could cause a problem is something preventing the expression (or `g`) from evaluating normally, e.g. `Hold[g[1+1+1+1]]`, some symbol with a `Hold*` attribute, or something like `Block[{g}, g[1+1+1+1]]`. For this, if you want a *True* alias in your notebook, you can define `$Pre` to be a function which changes any occurrence of `g` to `Length`. `$Pre` is a global variable applied to any input expression before any sort of evaluation of it begins whatsoever.

Let me know if any of this is unclear, or if you have further questions!

---

**Alternatively:** Now, let's say you want something more complicated—not just substituting one function for another. Maybe one function for a *list* of two others.

For that, we can exploit the attribute `HoldAllComplete`. This intervenes *immediately* after the head is evaluated, and skips *all* evaluation of arguments (even upvalues), going directly to the step where we apply downvalues. So, for example,

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAllComplete];
f[x_] := {Length[x], Length[x]}

f[Unevaluated[1 + 1 + 1 + 1]]

(* Out: {4, 4} *)
```

`HoldAllComplete` has caused the arguments to be *immediately* substituted into the downvalue definition. So, by "skipping right to the downvalue step", we've replicated `Length` with downvalues instead of ownvalues—that is, with argument-taking definitions instead of something of the form `f = Length` or `f := Length` (which, by the way, would both work!)

---

**Aside:** There is another way to try to answer this question, which is to compare the definitions of the symbols via the undocumented function `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` or `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``. The problem is that this only helps us compare definitions for *user-defined symbols*, as the downvalues for `Length` are built-in, and so don't have Mathematica-visible downvalues. (Try it—you'll get an empty `DefinitionList`!) So, it's not necessarily relevant here, but I wanted to mention it as a way to inspect symbol behavior in certain contexts.

Comment: Really really thank you! I add a few things to improve reader's understanding : Read the first appearing 1. 2. 3. on and on until you get used to. The second appearing 2., 'Last time' means 'previous example', and 'from scratch' means 'from the beginning'.

Comment: @imidak nice, thanks for the suggestions, I've edited it to match! :)