# How can I try to debug this discrepancy between Map and ParallelMap?

Tags: parallelization, chemistry

It is hard for me to present the actual set of functions that is prompting this question, because it is part of a very large code base. But to summarise, I have a setup like the following:

```
ClearAll[f, g1, g2];

f[mol_Molecule] := (* Transform mol and return a new molecule; f in pure *);

g1[lst : {__Molecule}] := Map[f, lst];

g2[lst : {__Molecule}] := ParallelMap[f, lst];
```

The argument `lst` usually has about 1,000 molecules, and the parallel version runs about 12 times faster on my computer. But while the function `g1` ***always*** returns the correct result, the function `g2` *sometimes* does not.

I understand that this is hardly enough detail. But I am quite baffled, and looking for pointers on what could cause such an error, and what I should try to inspect. The documentation clearly states that `ParallelMap` "*...automatically distributes different applications of f among different kernels and processors,*" so I assumed that `ParallelMap` could be used as a drop-in replacement for `Map`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

*EDIT*

flinty has brought up a very relevant point that I forgot to mention in the question. The function `f` is a pure function and does not mutate any variable.

Comment: I wonder if this question might have relevance: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138476/parallelize-map-and-parallelmap?rq=1

Comment: Is your `f` a pure function? If it has some state associated with it then `ParallelMap` might not give a result consistent with `Map`. Consider the following `f[x_] := (y++; Return[x + y]);
y = 0; Map[f, {1, 2, 3, 4}]` then try: `y = 0; ParallelMap[f, {1, 2, 3, 4}]` and you'll probably get a different result.

Comment: @flinty yes, the entire code base consists of pure functions. There is no state mutation anywhere.

Comment: There could still be global state in a built-in function or package function somewhere. We'd need a minimal failing example `f` to test it.

Comment: Understood. I will try to condense the code down to something small and digestible, so that I can post it here.

Comment: If you can condense this down to a reproducible example, even if it needs to be run multiple times to demonstrate the problem, you should submit it to Wolfram Technical support, either [on the web](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback) or in-product via Help->Give Feedback.  I can take a look at it then.